# MFC x64 Release Version using crashes on startup about 30% of the time with Access Violation?

Tags: winapi, mfc, crash

An MFC app crashes on startup at the same place about 30% of the time.  I have seen the debug version crash a couple times, but not nearly as often as the release version.

It appears to be internal to MFC `LoadState()` processing.  If you delete the `workspace` before each start then it never crashes.

I've created a sample project to reproduce the problem.  It's located at the following link: [LoadStateBug Example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7yc7uzs8in5pc9f/loadstatebug.zip?dl=0)

I'm using VS2017.  Extract the zip, load the project, use x64 / release build. To make it crash, I press F5, click the X to close the window and repeat over and over, within 10 times you should see the crash (sometimes it takes a few more).

Is there something in the sample causing it or is it MFC?  If MFC, is there a fix or workaround.

Thanks.

Comment: See what's at `myapp!CMainFrame::LoadFrame+0x35` for a starting point. Also, if you build the release *with* symbols and debug it inside VS you get more easy-to-use information than in a crash dump.

Comment: Just the normal: if (!CFrameWndEx::LoadFrame(nIDResource, dwDefaultStyle, pParentWnd, pContext))
 {
  return FALSE;
 }

Comment: It appears to be in MFC?

Comment: The top of the stack is in MFC code, indeed, but just because it eventually crashes there doesn't mean it's an MFC bug. Apparently some object is NULL at a point where MFC didn't expect it to be, but to find which one and why will take some debugging.

Comment: The path is all the standard stuff, which is why I sent OnCreate which is the only part of my code that is called in that call path after the LoadFrame request (I put debug output messages to all functions to see what was called).  Again, it works 70% of the time.  I should check my MFC dll version?

Comment: 70% hit rate counts as lucky, the tough ones are bugs that happen once in thousands runs. I presume you use VC++ since it's about MFC, so you have all you need to debug it, step by step if needed. Btw `static linked MFC to be able to step in` is a misconception, you can debug into the MFC sources regardless of static vs. dynamic linking, and regardless of debug vs. release builds as long as you build with debugging information turned on.

Comment: updated to v14.26.28720.03 but still does it.   I've seen other MFC apps on the internet report the same issue.  There is nothing left, the init process is all the standard stuff, it never gets to any of my special code, just what I posted above in `OnCreate` (which is pretty standard too).  F11 step into doesn't work for me when MFC function called and using DLL's. (treats it like F10 step over)

Comment: Something is not right with your settings in that case. Your next best bet would be to trim it down an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post it here.

Comment: It appears to be within the whole `LoadState()` logic.  `CMFCMenuBar` calls `MFCToolBar` chain and sometimes it crashes.  If I put in code to delete the `WorkSpace` in the registry, it works without any crashing.

Comment: Re: ` It's pretty boiler plate` - what exactly have you changed there?

Comment: I uploaded a sample project a while ago that will crash on startup.   I have updated the original message with the link

Comment: @user3161924 I have a similar problem with an app and it is also to do with the `WorkSpace` in the registry, and I find it hard to track down. Did you get any where with this?

Comment: moved to use the bcgsoft version.